# error: non-static method (datatype[]) cannot be referenced from a static context AND incompatible types: int cannot be converted to int[]

Tags: c#

I am getting the error message above from Ignition(non-static method (datatype[]) cannot be referenced from a static context) as commented in the code below and I also the error (incompatible types: int cannot be converted to int[]) when trying to call int dist in method moveHorizontally and moveVertically which contains declared arrays. Take note ignitions, xPosition, yPosition and color are all initialized arrays of size 10. Please, how to I remove these errors.

```
switch (op) {

              case "1" : ignitions = iginitionSwitch(ignitions[i]); // non-*static method iginitionSwitch(boolean[]) cannot be referenced from a static context*

                           reportState(ignitions, yPosition, xPosition, color );

                           reportState(ignitions, yPosition, xPosition, color);
                    break;

            case "2": System.out.print("In which direction do you want to move the car? \n H: Horizontal \n V: Vertical Direction: ");
                        String direction1 =scan.nextLine();


                       System.out.print("Enter a movement distance: ");

                          int dist= scan.nextInt(); // *trying to call int dist in method moveHorizontally and moveVertically which contains declared arrays*


                       scan.nextLine();


                       reportState(ignitions, yPosition, xPosition, color);
            if ( direction1.equals("H") ) {

                       xPosition = moveHorizontally(dist, xPosition, ignitions);    //dist,
                       reportState(ignitions, yPosition, xPosition, color);

                             break;                 
                                  }
        else if ( direction1.equals("V")) {


                     yPosition = moveHorizontally( dist, yPosition, ignitions);  //dist is called in this method
                    reportState(ignitions, yPosition, xPosition, color);

                           }

                break;

     case "Q": 
                finished = true;
                System.exit( 0 );
```

Comment: See marked duplicate for "non-static" issue. Your other error is similarly straightforward to anyone who actually reads the error message text and then uses that message as guidance to inspect the code. You are trying to pass an `int` value where an `int[]` reference is expected. You should practice reading compiler error messages and fixing your code based on them yourself, but if you believe you really must post a question here, you also need to make sure you provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: Well, @ Peter am sure it's not wrong to be a beginner in something. You didn't suddenly wake up to be at this level of programming. Thanks, I would do more research.